# style li in a tag with nth-child()

Tags: html, css

I want style li tags with nth-child but these `li` tags are in `a` tag! like this:

```
<ul>
    <a href=""><li>this is test </li></a>
    <a href=""><li>this is test </li></a>
    <a href=""><li>this is test </li></a>
    <a href=""><li>this is test </li></a>
</ul>
```

And style:

```
a:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-right: 2px solid #666;
}
    
.li:hover{
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
}
```

But it doesn't work. I think li tag should be child of the ul tag.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53524781/how-to-set-focus-in-li-elements-using-tabindex/53525142#53525142) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your css you had: `.li` and that targets elements with li class ( sucha as `<div class="li">`), not li elements.

You are right, li should be the direct child of ul tag:

```css
ul li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-right: 2px solid #666;
 }

ul li:hover{
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="">this is test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">this is test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">this is test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">this is test</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you want the background of the links only and not all the list items:

```css
ul li:nth-child(even) a {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-right: 2px solid #666;
}

ul li:hover a {
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="">this is test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">this is test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">this is test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">this is test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help